# Why is Java 6 receiving a different SSL certificate chain than Java 7?

Tags: java, ssl

We've reconfigured one of our servers to change the hostname of one of its virtual host.

Our server config went from :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.olddomain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    SSLCertificateFile "D:/Security/wildcard/OLDDOMAIN.COM.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Security/wildcard/OLDDOMAIN.COM.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/Security/wildcard/CertChain.crt"

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

to:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName test.newdomain.com
    ServerAlias test.olddomain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL

    SSLCertificateFile "D:/Security/wildcard/NEWDOMAIN.COM.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "D:/Security/wildcard/NEWDOMAIN.COM.key"
    SSLCertificateChainFile "D:/Security/wildcard/CertChain.crt"

    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

With any web browser, we can access the site just fine, we don't have any certificate issues. However when I try accessing a URL from Java 6 and I'm getting this error:

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching test.newdomain.com found
```

I tried running java with the -Djavax.net.debug=SSL option and strangely java is getting the certificate of the olddomain:

```
*** Certificate chain
chain [X] = [
[
  Version: VX
  Subject: CN=*.olddomain.com, O=COMPANY, L=Place, ST=ST, C=US
  Signature Algorithm: SHAXwithRSA, OID = X.X.XXX.XXXXXX.X.X.X

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, XXXX bits
  modulus:     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
  public exponent: XXXXX
  Validity: [From: Tue Jan XX XX:XX:XX EST XXXX,
               To: Fri Feb XX XX:XX:XX EST XXXX]
  Issuer: CN=DigiCert High Assurance CA-X, OU=www.digicert.com, O=DigiCert Inc, C=US
  SerialNumber: [    XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX XXXXXXXX]
```

However, if I replace java6 with java7. It correctly reads the proper certificate and I'm able to access the URL.

What am I missing here? I do see slightly different handshake from java6 to java7 but I don't think that would explain getting different certificates.

Java6 handshake:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
***
pool-1-thread-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 95
pool-1-thread-1, WRITE: SSLv2 client hello message, length = 131
pool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 81
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Created:  [Session-4, SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
pool-1-thread-1, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4313
```

java7 handshake:

```
*** ClientHello, TLSv1
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, sect163k1, sect163r2, secp192r1, secp224r1,sect233k1, sect23
 sect409k1, sect409r1, secp521r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp160k1, secp160r1, secp160r2,  sect163r1, secp192k1, se9k1,     secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension server_name, server_name: [host_name: test.newdomain.com]
***
pool-5-thread-2, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 181
pool-5-thread-2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 85
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
Cipher Suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension server_name, server_name:
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA]
** TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
pool-5-thread-2, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 4312
```

Can anyone explain why java6 might be behaving differently from java7 and web browsers, and how to fix this?

In case it makes a difference, this is the code I'm using to test connectivity. Nothing fancy:

```
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://test.newdomain.com/myapp");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        in = conn.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("OpenStream didn't fail!");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex.getClass().getName()+ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("Connection failed");
    } finally {
        try {
            if (in != null)
                in.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: The difference is undoubtedly because java7 (Https)URLConn, like (all? major?) browsers, sends Server Name Indication (SNI) but java6 didn't, as  your debug-output confirms. A named-vhost server needs SNI to specify the desired host and thus certificate, and without SNI must do some default, which is apparently wrong in your case, but I don't know enough httpd to say exactly where to look.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment Dave. We were thinking something along those lines but I did not know about SNI. At least I now have something to investigate. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question based on input provided by date_thompson_085.

The issue is that the request is always sent using the IP address and the hostname is contained in the http headers. However, with SSL, that hostname information is encrypted. So when SSL handshake is occurring, it doesn’t yet know the hostname. Because of this it doesn't know which virtual host the request should go to and returns the first (or default) certificates, in our case olddomain.com which is the wrong one.

The reason why browsers and java7 are not affected is because they send Server Name Indication (SNI) as part of the SSL information. This way, apache knows what virtual host to use before starting SSL handshake and returns the proper certificate. Java 6 doesn't support SNI.